# PHP Foreach array function

Tags: php, arrays, function, foreach

I'm looking to do a simple checker to look at a port and say yes online or no offline I have some code to do this I want to put an array in a look it, just come a bit stuck my PHP coding is not all that good.

I'm stuck with

```
if (!function_exists(checkUDP))   {
        function checkUDP(&$array){
        $fp = fsockopen("udp://".$host, $port, $errno, $errstr,1.0);
        if (!$fp) {
        return false;
```

I'm trying to get the port and IP in from the array.

---

```
$array = [
    [ 80, '216.58.198.163','www 1'],
    [ 80, '216.58.198.163', 'www 2'],
];
    set_error_handler('my_error_handler');
    function my_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {}

    foreach ($array as list($port, $ip, $name)) {

if (!function_exists(checkUDP))   {
    function checkUDP(&$array){
    $fp = fsockopen("udp://".$host, $port, $errno, $errstr,1.0);
    if (!$fp) {
    return false;
    }
         else {
        fclose($fp);
        return true;
        }
    }
}
    $online = '<li class="tick">';
    $offline = '<li class="cross">';

    if(checkUDP($ip)){
    echo $online. $name. 'Online</li>',$ip.':' ,$port ;
    }
        else{
        echo $offline. $name. 'Offline</li>',$ip.':' ,$port ;
        }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: _just come a bit stuck..._ Stuck on what? Please describe a specific issue, the current vs expected behaviour/results/outputs

Comment: Why are you defining your checkUDP() function inside a loop in the first place? Define it outside the loop. Modify it so that it accepts the required arguments, nd pass those arguments when you call it

Comment: so fixed it but if a server was offline it showed as being online.